# Display Highest 3 marks with duplicate records

Tags: mysql

My table is

[image]

I would like to display highest 3 marks of each section on a page, But if anyone got similar Marks in Top 3 Marks, I would like to display that duplicate Marks as well according to Marks in Descending order. I am using following code.

```
SELECT Name, Marks FROM mytable AS t1 
INNER JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT(Marks) AS best_marks FROM mytable ORDER BY Marks DESC LIMIT 3) AS t2 ON t1.Marks = t2.best_marks ORDER BY Marks DESC, Name ASC;
```

So my final out put looks,

[image]

Please help me... I am struggling for the solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a trick to get the top three marks using `group_concat()` and `substring_index()`.  The idea is to get the top three in a list.  Then to use `find_in_set()` to match into that list:

```
select name, marks
from mytable t1 join
     (select section, substring_index(group_concat(distinct Marks order by Marks desc), ',', 3) as Marks3
      from mytable
      group by section
     ) tsum
     on t1.section = tsum.section and
        find_in_set(t1.Marks, tsum.Marks3) > 0
ORDER BY Marks DESC, Name ASC;
```

[Here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8eb7e/4) is a SQLFiddle that illustrates that the code is syntactically correct.

Comment: Warning: mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in , shows this error

Comment: This seems to work perfectly for me. I have extended the original SQLFiddle to do all the inserts and show the results http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/82928/8

Comment: Dear friend, Please check this, only 1 record is displaying

http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6afaa/1